# How to use AnimatedVisibility with nullable values?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I find myself in this situation quite often. I have some value like `plates` in the sample below, and I want to show/hide it depending on if its null or not. But hiding it always fails since nothing is rendered whenever its null, and the animation just snaps to empty nothingness.

**How can I make this work? Id like to keep **`plates`** around until the animation finishes.**

```
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = plates != null,
        content = {
            if (plates != null) {
                // Render plates
            } else {
                // The animation snaps to nothingness, as opposed to animating out
            }
        })
```

Comment: If you want the content to show during the "exit" portion of the animation, the content cannot be null. The content must be the exact same content when the "enter" phase was executed, otherwise, the animation will show a very quick change. Why is your plates variable null all of a sudden if it wasn't null when the "enter" phase was executed?

Comment: Exactly my thinking. So I should remember the content, and update it everytime a non-null value comes in - then use its value in the animatedVisibility block, while specifying its visibility by the last value being null or not? As for the value becoming null again, it just indicates that it shouldnt be shown any longer.

Comment: That is the correct solution. Just cache your last item and reuse it when hiding. Also, if your screen uses vertical scrolling, you should place the scrollstate in your viewmodel and pass that to your composable because animation destroys the scrollstate. Using a local state like rememberScrollState will not work. It gets destroyed. The exit will look smoother without jumping back to the top of the screen that is exiting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, and it works as expected!

```
@Composable
inline fun <T> AnimatedValueVisibility(
    value: T?,
    enter: EnterTransition = fadeIn(
        animationSpec = FloatSpec
    ) + expandVertically(
        animationSpec = SizeSpec,
        clip = false
    ),
    exit: ExitTransition = fadeOut(
        animationSpec = FloatSpec
    ) + shrinkVertically(
        animationSpec = SizeSpec,
        clip = false
    ),
    crossinline content: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    val ref = remember {
        Ref<T>()
    }

    ref.value = value ?: ref.value

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = value != null,
        enter = enter,
        exit = exit,
        content = {
            ref.value?.let { value ->
                content(value)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up solving this issue

```kotlin
/**
 * Wrapper around [AnimatedVisibility] that remembers the last state so that a nullable
 * state value can be used. Otherwise only the animate in works and the animate out is just
 * a quick flash.
 */
@Composable
inline fun <T> AnimatedNullableVisibility(
    value: T?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enter: EnterTransition = fadeIn() + expandVertically(),
    exit: ExitTransition = fadeOut() + shrinkVertically(),
    crossinline content: @Composable (scope: AnimatedVisibilityScope, T) -> Unit
) {
    val ref = remember {
        Ref<T>()
    }

    ref.value = value ?: ref.value

    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = modifier,
        visible = value != null,
        enter = enter,
        exit = exit,
        content = {
            ref.value?.let { value ->
                content(this, value)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party, but there is also the `AnimatedContent` composable. It still requires an opt-in to the `ExperimentalAnimationApi`, however it will pass the model back down through its composable lambda parameter, and you can check that one for nullability. Here's how it would work:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContent
import androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun AnimatedPlates(plates: Plates?) {
    AnimatedContent(plates) { plates ->
        if (plates != null) {
            // Render plates
        } else {
            // Render either nothing, or some empty state.
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those in 2024, I just tested this solution:

```
val param = remember {...}
val delayedParam = remember {...}

val openView() {
    param.value = delayedParam.value = "..."
}

// Insert other components here if you want.

val currentParam = param.value
val currentDelayedParam = delayedParam.value
AnimatedVisibility(visible = currentParam != null) {
    val elvisParam = currentParam ?: currentDelayedParam
    if (elvisParam != null) {
        YourView(param = elvisParam)
    }
}
```

It worked for the entering and exiting animations.

Answer (score -1):

Animation always requires content even when there is nothing to show. Just display a Surface when the content is null (or empty):

```kotlin
AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = plates != null,
        content = {
            if (plates != null) {
                // Render plates
            } else {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { }
            }
        })
```

Comment: This has the same effect, when plates becomes null, the empty surface is rendered and it looks like the plates immediately disappear.